CUPS stuck on "Processing page 1..." - Brother HL-L2300D
I have a Brother HL-L2300D that I bought used. I have it connected by USB to a Raspberry Pi running CUPS, with the printer driver from printer-driver-brlaser. I can send jobs to the printer, but they never get past a State of "Processing Page 1..." until eventually, maybe hours later, they disappear from the job queue and don't show in Completed Jobs or All Jobs. The printer also never makes any noises or changes its LED pattern to indicate it's trying to do something.
What can I do to figure out why it's getting stuck?

You probably need to install the Brother drivers for Linux before anything else.

@ChanganAuto isn't that covered by the printer-driver-brlaser?

No,it isn't. I meant the proprietary drivers.

@ChanganAuto I don't get why additional, proprietary drivers would be required, though. My understanding is that printer-driver-brlaser is based on a PPD extracted from one of Brother's downloads so that we don't need to go through installing Brother's proprietary stuff. Are you speculating or do you have some source or experience you're relying on?

I have some experience with Brother printers indeed. I always had to install the proprietary drivers.
